# MongoDB: Sum total of nested array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have a database structure like this:

```
users = [
    {
        firstName: 'John',
        transactions: [transaction]
    },
    {
        firstName: 'Jane',
        transactions: [transaction]
    },

]
```

I tried this to no avail.

```
users.aggregate([
    { $match: { transactions: { $exists: true }}},
    { $project: { count: { $size: '$transactions '}}},
    { $group: { total: { $sum: '$count'}}}
]);
```

What's the correct way to sum the total number of transactions for *all* users in the database?

I tried using an aggregate, but I wasn't able to get it to work properly. Any help would be really appreciated.